# GMSCoordinateBounds corner values - Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I want to display the visible markers only in the visible region of the screen, but I get only -180 values. Same result on simulator and iPad device.

Code:

```
  GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = [mapView.projection visibleRegion];
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithRegion:visibleRegion];

[mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds]];

CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = bounds.northEast;
CLLocationCoordinate2D northWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(bounds.northEast.latitude, bounds.southWest.longitude);
CLLocationCoordinate2D southEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(bounds.southWest.latitude, bounds.northEast.longitude);
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = bounds.southWest;

NSLog(@"NORTH-EST: %.5f",northEast.latitude);
NSLog(@"NORTH-EST: %.5f",northEast.longitude);

NSLog(@"NORTH-WEST: %.5f",northWest.latitude);
NSLog(@"NORTH-WEST: %.5f",northWest.longitude);

NSLog(@"South-EST: %.5f",southEast.longitude);
NSLog(@"South-EST: %.5f",southEast.latitude);

NSLog(@"SOUTH-WEST: %.5f",southWest.latitude);
NSLog(@"SOUTH-WEST: %.5f",southWest.longitude);
```

Log:

```
Printing description of visibleRegion:
(GMSVisibleRegion) visibleRegion = {
nearLeft = (latitude = -180, longitude = -180)
nearRight = (latitude = -180, longitude = -180)
farLeft = (latitude = -180, longitude = -180)
farRight = (latitude = -180, longitude = -180)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution for this problem:

Source code:

```
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = [mapView.projection visibleRegion];
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithRegion:visibleRegion];

CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = bounds.northEast;
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = bounds.southWest;
```

The visibleRegion only works on a **real device IOS Device** NOT on the simulator.